# Usando Tkinter junto a um Banco de dados

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Estou fazendo um programa de cadastro de pessoas com interface (ainda bem básico, só para fazer testes) e estou com várias dificuldades:

- Estou extraindo os dados usando o `.get()`, porém, eu só consigo digitar 1 caractere. Se eu digitar mais aparece o seguinte erro: *Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied*.

Código:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import time
import datetime




connection = sqlite3.connect('Main_9_DB.db')
c = connection.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teste (ed text)')

create_table()



def dataentry():

    c.execute('INSERT INTO teste (ed)VALUES (?)',(ed.get()))
    connection.commit()





def bt_onclick():
   # print(ed.get())
    dataentry()

janela = Tk()
var = StringVar()   
ed = Entry(janela, bd = 2, textvariable = var)
ed.place(x = 50, y = 100)

bt = Button(janela, width=20, text="OK", command=bt_onclick)
bt.place(x = 50, y = 150)

lb = Label(janela, text="Label")
lb.place(x = 100, y = 200)


janela.geometry("300x300+300+300")
janela.mainloop()
```

Se poderem me responder, desde já fico agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

É por que o segundo parâmetro do execute - onde você está passando o "ed.get()", deve ser uma sequência - isso é, mesmo que você vá usar apenas uma substituição na query (que é o caso, você tem só um "(?)" na sua string), esse parâmetro deve normalmente ser uma lista ou uma tupla, com os valores que você quer substituir dentro.

Como em Python uma string é uma sequência válida, quando você não põe a string retornada pelo `get` dentro de uma lista ou uma tupla, ele passa cada caractere da string como um elemento da sequência. Por isso, com uma única letra funciona - mas com duas ou mais letras, ele fala que tem parâmetros a mais.

Fica fácil ver quando usamos o método "join" de strings - ele também espera uma sequência, e se passamos uma string, ele faz a mesma coisa: trata cada elemento da string como um item da sequência:

```
In [47]: ",".join("teste")
Out[47]: 't,e,s,t,e'
```

O correto é:

```
In [48]: ",".join(("teste",))
Out[48]: 'teste'
```

O essencial aí é a `,` logo após a string - desta forma o Python entende que esse parênteses de dentro é "uma tupla com um único elemento", e não "um parênteses em volta da string" - que é o que acontece no seu código.

Se você não quer depender dessa "," pode passar o seu parâmetro para o execute como uma lista - nesse caso, a vírgula extra não é necessária.
Ou seja - mude a linha do seu "execute" para ficar como abaixo:

```
def dataentry():

    c.execute('INSERT INTO teste (ed) VALUES (?)',[ed.get()])
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Muito obrigadoooooooo,funcionou graças a sua dica kk